# How to get link href from Custom Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm new to AngularJS. I am dynamically loading pages, which works fine. Each page has a unique color associated with it. I need to highlight an item in my page with that unique color when a user navigates to a page. The HTML in my view for this functionality, looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav navmenu-nav">
  <li ng-repeat="page in $myPages.allPages" use-custom-color>
    <a ng-href="#{{page.url}}"> <i class="{{page.icon}}">&nbsp;</i><span>{{page.name}}></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In an attempt to create a directive that will highlight the selected nav item with the custom color, I have the
following:

```
.directive('useCustomColor', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: [
        '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$location', '$myPages',
        function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location, $myPages) {
          var route = function() {
            return $location.path();
          };

          var setSelected = function(path) {  
            return angular.forEach($myPages.allPages, function(page) {
              if (page.url === path) {
                // find the matching link
                angular.forEach($element.find('a'), function(link) {
                  var $link = angular.element(link);
                  console.log(link);
                  console.log($link);
                  console.log($link.href);
                });
              }
            });
          };

          return $scope.$watch(route, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            return setSelected($location.path());
          });
        }
      ]
    };
  }
])
```

The odd part is, when setSelected is called, I can't get the href value of the anchor tag. I need that value. However do I get the href of the link in the li?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`angular.element` is an alias for the `jQuery` function. You should do something like this:

```
$link.attr('href');
```

1. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element
2. http://api.jquery.com/attr/